# Google Apps Script -- Hide "Running Script" notification

Tags: google-apps-script

When running the Google Apps Script from the Sheets it shows a popup saying

> Running Script

with option to "cancel" or "dismiss".

I do not want to give my users these options. How can I **hide** the message at all or after a few seconds?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to dismiss this message when you are in the script editor, it is the way of working.

When you are in the sheet if for example you use a button with an attached function you will have a 'cancel' option and you can't dismiss it.

Only way to avoid this kind of message is to develop an add-on. With add-on you have the application loaded in the sidebar on the right and when user interact with add-on there is no message.

But this will imply more development than just coding the function you need.

Stéphane

Comment: How do you create an add on for this purpose. I am looking to hide/disable the message as well.